# IIS7 hosted Website working on Iocalhost on server, but not on local computer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have hosted a website (ASP.NET MVC 4 Project) on IIS 7, and I can browse perfectly fine in the server.
But when I try to access the same URL from my local computer in my broswer, it is not working, but I am able to ping the server from my local machine.

I'm new to IIS7, and I'm more of a developer then a administrator.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The way of deploying the MVC application is quite different.As its working fine on IIS,then it should be accessible through same system's browser.
There are only two cases in which the application can be accessible through IIS.
1.IIS with shared environment or on same network place.
2.IIS which connected to the same system.

So if its deployed on the IIS of the same system through whcih you are accessing the application using browser,then it would be accessible through browser.